# Sending value to a solidity contract method from web3 results in `Invalid Tuple Value` error

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, contract-debugging, nodejs

I'm sending values to a `solidity 0.5.1` method using `web3` and keep getting an `invalid Tuple value` error.

Here's the relevant contract code:

```
struct mystruct {
    bytes32 id; 
    string str;
}

mapping (bytes32 => mystruct) structs;

function creatMyStruct(bytes32 id, string memory str) public {
    mystruct memory newStruct = mystruct(id, str);
    structs[id] = newStruct;
}
```

I'm calling this from `node.js`:

```
contract.methods.creatMyStruct(someId, someString).send({from: fromAccount, gas: gasEstimate})
    .then(receipt => {
       var txhash = receipt.transactionHash;
       resolve(txhash);
    },
    (error) => {
        reject(error);
    }).catch((err) => {
         reject(err);
    });
```

I tried sending a `string`, a `number`, and converting the string to `hex`. The same error: `invalid tuple value`. What am I missing?

EDIT: here are some of the values I tried for `id`, which is the one that causes the problem. The `string` values below were tried when the `id` value was defined as a `string` in the contract, and the numeric ones when it was defined as `bytes32`. I can use both, so a solution for either one would be great.

```
let id = '123'; 
id = "hello"; 
id = '0xabca00000000000000000000000000';
id = 0xabca00000000000000000000000000;
id = 1;
id = 12300000000000000000000000000000;
id = 'hello';
```

I tried both as is, or by converting to `hex`:

```
userId = web3.utils.asciiToHex(userId);
```

The same error is generated for all of them. Here's a bit more description in the error:

```
reason: 'invalid tuple value',
code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
coderType: 'tuple',
value: '0x68656c6c6f'
```

Comment: The error implies that the problem is either with the value of `someId` or the value of `someString` or both. Your question implies that you under that. However, you have not included either one of them here; are we supposed to guess what they are or how you initialize them???

Comment: @goodvibration I added some of the values I tried.

Comment: I went back to compiler version 0.4.24. Problem gone.

Answer (score 0):

As you define the input parameter to be `bytes32`, the function expects a specific length of `bytes` to be valid. You would need to pad your input to 32 bytes.

E.g. `id = '0xabca00000000000000000000000000';` shall be `id = '0xabca000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000';`